# Externalization with Asymptote

Tags: graphics, diagrams, asymptote, externalize

There is a way to externalize pictures with Latex. I've created a folder qwe in the directory where my main document.tex sits and typed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=qwe/]
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw
    (3,-1) coordinate (a) node[right] {a}
    -- (0,0) coordinate (b) node[left] {b}
    -- (2,2) coordinate (c) node[above right] {c}
    pic["$\alpha$", draw=red, <->, angle eccentricity=1.2, angle radius=1cm]
    {angle=a--b--c};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Works like a charm! Although, I create Asymptote pictures.

**Is there any analog to externalize TikZ library but for Asymptote? And how to use it?**

(I have ~300 pictures in Asymptote and want to save time waiting until they all are being compiled. I bumped into externalzie option when I have the same problem with TikZ)

Comment: You could try using the [`asypictureB`](https://ctan.org/pkg/asypictureb?lang=en) package, which attempts to recompile only images that have changes.

Answer (score 1):

What I did (do when using asymptote) is to process the figures separately to PDF, and use `\pgfimage{}` (from the `pgf` package) to include it in the document. That way, complex images (like some 3D ones, that take quite a while to process) are only recompiled when they change (very rarely). That way, I can look at/tweak the images separately.